# python 3 map/lambda method with 2 inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax, lambda

I have a dictionary like the following in python 3:

```
ss = {'a':'2', 'b','3'}
```

I want to convert all he values to int using `map` function, and I wrote something like this:

```
list(map(lambda key,val: int(val), ss.items())))
```

but the python complains:

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'

My question is how can I write a `lambda` function with two inputs (E.g. key and val)

Comment: You've written it with two parameters just fine, but the problem is it is only being called with a single argument, a tuple `(key, val)`.

Comment: If you don't want to do anything with the keys, why don't you just map on `ss.values()`?

Comment: You need to use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of plain `map` as it unpacks the arguments for us(but only if you're using both keys and values, otherwise it's unnecessary as BrenBarn pointed out).
In Python 2 it was possible using simple tuple argument unpacking: `lambda (key, val): int(val)`.

Comment: Have you considered dict comprehension: `{k: int(v) for k, v in ss.items()}` Or if you want to modify the dict inplace: `for k, v in ss.items(): ss[k] = int(v)`

Comment: If you need only values then: `values = map(int, ss.values())`

Comment: Thanks every one for their correct comments. especially Ashwini,For the difference between python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ss.items()` will give an iterable, which gives tuples on every iteration. In your `lambda` function, you have defined it to accept two parameters, but the tuple will be treated as a single argument. So there is no value to be passed to the second parameter.

1. You can fix it like this

   ```
   print(list(map(lambda args: int(args[1]), ss.items())))
   # [3, 2]
   ```
2. If you are ignoring the keys anyway, simply use `ss.values()` like this

   ```
   print(list(map(int, ss.values())))
   # [3, 2]
   ```
3. Otherwise, [as suggested by Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543349/python-3-map-lamda-method-with-2-inputs/26543472#comment41710823_26543349), using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap),

   ```
   from itertools import starmap
   print(list(starmap(lambda key, value: int(value), ss.items())))
   # [3, 2]
   ```
4. I would prefer the List comprehension way

   ```
   print([int(value) for value in ss.values()])
   # [3, 2]
   ```

In Python 2.x, you could have done that like this

```
print map(lambda (key, value): int(value), ss.items())
```

This feature is called *Tuple parameter unpacking*. But this is removed in Python 3.x. Read more about it in [PEP-3113](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Comment: Any other ways you fancy mentioning? :p

Comment: Option zero is to call `ss.values()`: `result = map(int, ss.values())`

Comment: Thank you for the holistic response. also thanks Ashwini for starmaps. I didnt know that difference in python 2 and 3. which was my main problem.