# Gensim/Python - mapping document ids to documents, in sorted()

Tags: python, lambda, gensim

Would like to  obtain an identifiable list of most relevant documents (to LDA model) using gensim, i.e. exactly as the OP in the link below

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/lHi2MhoNDsY has the relevant answer, but not sure of how to get this to work:

```
tops = sorted(zip(my_ids, all_documents)), reverse=True, \
key=lambda my_id, doc: abs(dict(doc).get(topic_number, 0.0)))
```

Apart from a parenthesis that seems to be in the wrong place, the two main questions are:

1. How should my_ids be generated (do these map to the documents or to the words)? Something like `my_ids = [my_id for my_id in range(len(all_documents))]`
   throws

lambda () missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc'

2. What is the reason for this error, and how should `key=lambda my_id, doc: abs(dict(doc).get(topic_number, 0.0)))` be understood? Would `abs(dict(doc).get(topic_number, 0.0))` be unpacked as needed if the correct `my_ids` is supplied, or is some other fix needed?
   Also have had a look at [python 3 map/lambda method with 2 inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543349/python-3-map-lambda-method-with-2-inputs), but still unenlightened so far.